# sql must declare scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is a very simple question but i cannot find the answer anywhere on this site. I'm trying to get a for loop to go to 30 in SQL, but I get "must declare the scalar variable "@count"." each time I try to run this.

my code just looks like this:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @total_count INT;
SELECT @total_count = COUNT (1)
FROM #ACTIVES

WHILE @count < @total_count
begin
        --test statement
        @count = @count + 1
end
go
```

What am I doing wrong?
error occurs at the while statement

Comment: To make your example executable, add the definition of #ACTIVES. But in general, you are missing `SET` or `SELECT` before `@Count` on that line.

Comment: you should add `SET` or `SELECT` in your while loop to affect the variable

Comment: #ACTIVES is set in a SELECT statement above

Comment: SET still doesn't make the code work

Comment: This is most certainly an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/ I highly doubt this is the way you should be doing whatever you are doing. Loops of just horribly inefficient. Far better to use a set based approach.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `SET` when setting the value of a variable. Thus:

```
DECLARE @count int = 0;
DECLARE @total_count int;
SELECT @total_count = COUNT(1)
FROM #ACTIVES;

WHILE @count < @total_count
BEGIN
    --test statement
    SET @count = @count + 1;
END;
```

The better question here, however, is: *Why do you want to use a `WHILE` loop?* They are incredibly frowned open in SQL Server, when 99/100 times a dataset approach can be achieved.

To show that this does work:

```
CREATE TABLE #ACTIVES (i int);

WITH i AS(
     SELECT 1 AS n
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n + 1
     FROM i
     WHERE n +1 <= 30)
INSERT INTO #ACTIVES
SELECT n
FROM i;
GO

DECLARE @count int = 0;
DECLARE @total_count int;
SELECT @total_count = COUNT(1)
FROM #ACTIVES;

WHILE @count < @total_count
BEGIN
    --test statement
    SET @count = @count + 1;
    PRINT 'Loop ' + CONVERT(varchar(2),@Count);
END;

GO
DROP TABLE #ACTIVES;
GO
```

This outputs the following:

```
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3
Loop 4
Loop 5
Loop 6
Loop 7
Loop 8
Loop 9
Loop 10
Loop 11
Loop 12
Loop 13
Loop 14
Loop 15
Loop 16
Loop 17
Loop 18
Loop 19
Loop 20
Loop 21
Loop 22
Loop 23
Loop 24
Loop 25
Loop 26
Loop 27
Loop 28
Loop 29
Loop 30
```

Comment: i've tried that, it still gives me the error1) [Code: 137, SQL State: S1000]  Must declare the scalar variable "@count".
2) [Code: 137, SQL State: S1000]  Must declare the scalar variable "@count".

Comment: I'm trying to loop through columns in #ACTIVES is why i'm using a while loop. is there a better sql statement to use?

Comment: @T.Fogarty the above does work (I've added a further example with data). IN regards to a "better" statement, I can't answer that question without knowing your actual goal.

Comment: thanks for your help (and sorry for questioning whether it works). I'm pretty sure there is just a problem with my machine, as the code is getting the errors again. my end goal is to loop through a column of actives and use the data from each row in the column

Comment: I ***assume*** that the SQL in your original post is an exactly copy and paste from your SQL in SSMS, and you don't have any `GO`'s before the last one in your example.

Comment: correct. I also made a new file and literally copied and pasted your code exactly, and it gave back an error.

Comment: @T.Fogarty the full working example, or the original statement? If the latter, something is wrong with your set up.

Comment: the full working example. I'm going to look into my setup. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *recursive* way :

```
DECLARE @total_count int
SELECT @total_count = count(1) from #ACTIVES

with t as (
     select 1 as cnt
     union all
     select cnt + 1
     from t
     where cnt < @total_count
)

select *
from t
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: `SET @total_count = count(1) from #ACTIVES` won't work. You need to use `SELECT` when referencing a dataset.

Comment: @Larnu. . . Yes, that i missed.